# Laravels Eloquent to store many to many relationship

Tags: laravel-4, save, many-to-many, eloquent

I have 3 tables

```
-- networks
    Schema::create('networks', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('network');
            $table->string('description',255);
            $table->string('attributes',255);
            $table->timestamps();

        });
```

and

```
-- campaigns

 Schema::create('campaigns', function($table) {
                $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('campaign_title');
                $table->integer('owner')->unsigned();
                $table->string('details');
                $table->timestamps();
            });

            Schema::table('campaigns', function($table) {
                $table->foreign('owner')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            });
```

and
    -- campaign_networks_relationhsips

```
Schema::table('campaign_networks_relationhsips', function($table)
    {
        $table->foreign('campaign_id')->references('id')->on('campaigns')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('network_id')->references('id')->on('networks')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

On new Campaign creation, in the Form I show available Networks as checkboxes.

User gives a title to the campaign and ads the desired Networks to it and saves.

**The question:**

has Eloquent a method which would pull this relation directly to the binding tables(campaign_networks_relationhsips) or I have to make 2 queries like saving the campaign and after getting the id of the campaign I use a loop on networks to save this relations in my binding table.

example

created campaign: gives me back id:1
choosed networks 3,4

than loop and save

```
1-3
1-4 

in campaign_networks_relationhsips
```

than I try the following

```
<?php namespace Td\Reports\Controllers\Backend;

use Td\Reports\Campaigns\CampaignsInterface;
use Input,
    Redirect,
    View,
    App,
    Str;
use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;
class CampaignsController extends ObjectBaseAdminController {

    /**
     * The place to find the views / URL keys for this controller
     * @var string
     */
    protected $view_key = 'admin.campaigns';

    protected $networks;

    /**
     * Construct
     */
    public function __construct(CampaignsInterface $campaigns) {
        $this->model = $campaigns;
        $networks = App::make('Td\Reports\Networks\NetworksInterface');
        $this->networks = $networks->getAll();
        parent::__construct();
    }

   public function postNew() {


        $record = $this->model->getNew(Input::all());
        //$record->campaign_title= Input::get('campaign_title');

        $valid = $this->validateWithInput === true ? $record->isValid(Input::all()) : $record->isValid();

        if (!$valid)
            return Redirect::to('admin/' . $this->new_url)->with('errors', $record->getErrors())->withInput();

        // Run the hydration method that populates anything else that is required / runs any other
        // model interactions and save it.
        $record->save();

        $record->networks()->sync([3,4]);

        return Redirect::to($this->object_url)->with('success', new MessageBag(array('Item Created')));
    }


}
```

than I have the repository for campaigns

```
<?php

namespace Td\Reports\Campaigns;

use Td\Reports\Core\EloquentBaseRepository;
use Td\Reports\Abstracts\Traits\NetworkableRepository;
use Datatables,Sentry;

class CampaignsRepository extends EloquentBaseRepository implements CampaignsInterface {


    /**
     * Construct
     * @param Campaigns $campaigns
     */
    public function __construct(Campaigns $campaigns) {
        $this->model = $campaigns;


    public function getAll() {

        if (Sentry::getUser()->hasAnyAccess(['system'])) {
            return $this->model->get();
        } else {
            return $this->model->where('owner', Sentry::getUser()->id)->get();
        }
    }

    public function networks()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Network', 'campaign_networks_relationhsips');
    }

}
```

Comment: Rephrase your question, you said nothing there

Comment: I re factorized my question I gave my best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A must read for you: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships

From what you wrote I assume you want to save a model and its pivot relations, so here it goes:

```
// basic example flow in a controller, repo or wherever you like
$campaign = new Campaign;
$campaign->name = Input::get('name');
// assign more campaign attributes
$campaign->save();

$campaign->networks()->sync([3,4]); // 3,4 are existing network rows ids
```

That's all. For the above to work you need to setup these relationships:

```
// Campaign model
public function networks()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('Network', 'campaign_networks_relationhsips');
}

// Network model
public function campaings()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('Campaign', 'campaign_networks_relationhsips');
}
```

Comment: I try to use your provided inside of my repository but I do not get to work I get Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sync(). What I did I added public function networks()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('Network', 'campaign_networks_relationhsips');
} to my Campaign repository so on the other to my Network Repository than from Controller I try to save datas but with the error above

Comment: I can't help you without the code. The error says you are trying to call `sync` on the `Builder` object, while it is a `BelongsToMany` method.

Comment: I made an update on the codes maybe u can guide me, that would appreciated

Comment: I suppose you have a magic `__call` on your base repo class, that forwards methods calls to the underlying Eloquent model, and that's where the errors occurs (?). Anyway don't define relationships in the repo, but on the models.

Comment: Yes there is a base repo and model, I placed the above code in the class which is extending my base model (Campaigns.php*,CampaignsInterface.php, CampaignsRepository.php) but still error Class 'Network' not found,but anyway from where should be loaded Network as class

Comment: than I have Networks.php, NetworksInterface.php, NetworksRepository.php , the first Networks extends EloquentBaseModel which extends Eloquent. Changing to Networks is the same class not found somehow I suppose the Networks model needs to be nested in Campaigns model, but how? The project was generated as workbench

Comment: Okay I got it to work so I can reference to related model in workbench return $this->belongsToMany('Td\Reports\Campaigns\Campaigns', 'campaign_networks_relationhsips');